# Why can't WiFi hardware be used to receive radio stations?

Tags: radio, wifi

Special hardware is needed to receive radio waves in different frequencies i.e a `RTL-SDR`.

My question is why can't the WiFi hardware get also used to pick up radio signals? Isn't WiFi just a radio signals running on a different frequency? (i.e 2.4 Ghz).

Is the hardware hardwired to only operate on such frequencies and they are not able to be modified via software or drivers?

Another way to put the question is, what is in an SDR kit like RTL-SDR that's not already in my laptop?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think this is what 'm trying to understand. What is in an SDR kit like `RTL-SDR` that's not already in my laptop?

Comment: Specialized radios have hardware components that are made for specific frequencies (filters, amplifiers and so on..). Moreover, complex stacks such as WiFi have also protocol-specific digital processing. In SDR case all these components are implemented in software instead, or have a configurable hardware, which is much more expensive (both cost-wise and size).

Comment: TimWescott gives a more detailed answer below.  But your question "Is the hardware hardwired to only operate on such frequencies and they are not able to be modified via software or drivers?" can be simply answered with a YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio) = Software Defined Radio. I.e. controlled from software. They have functionality for generic radio.

WiFi devices doesn't have SDR, instead the have a [baseband processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband_processor) which are the complex device targeted especially for the WiFi bands, modulation, etc. It can't be controlled from the software outside of those functionality. It just wasn't designed to be a generic SDR.

And no, this aren't for marketing reasons. It's just because it wasn't required. And implementing something what is not required for an end product to function is a waste of resources.

Comment: Then again, the whole RTL-SDR thing came about because some manufacturer decided to put an 8-bit I/Q ADC into a DVB-T stick to use as an FM radio receiver and let the host machine demodulate in software instead of using a fixed-function FM demodulator chip. Overkill solution to an unnecessary fluff feature, but it was cheap so it shipped :)

Answer (score 4):

This boils down to a design & manufacture 101 question.

A piece of kit that's designed to do one specific thing is always less complicated, and thus less expensive, than a piece of kit that can do lots of different things.

A SDR is a piece of kit that's designed to do lots of different things with an incoming radio, and it's designed to do so in a way that lets what it does be defined in software.

A WiFi device (or any single-purpose radio) is designed to do just one thing, it's designed to do it well, it's designed to do it with a minimal amount of hardware.  Because WiFi is so popular, a lot of engineering resources can go into designing the hardware to be cheap to manufacture -- a large part of being able to do that is locking down the scope of what the hardware has to do, and not making any special effort to make it easy or even possible to change what is done.

Comment: *A piece of kit that's designed to do one specific thing is always less complicated, and thus less expensive, than a piece of kit that can do lots of different things.* As a general rule, that is true. And I agree in terms of WiFi vs. SDR, etc. But consider that the microprocessor revolutions started with designs for single-chip CPUs to replace a dedicated calculator design - the idea that a general purpose processor, despite being *more* powerful/flexible/expandable - could do the job cheaper than the traditional method.